# AppEngine React and Jersey - The scratchDir you specified is unusable

Tags: java, reactjs, google-app-engine, jersey

I have a Java-based REST API (via Jersey 1.18) that I've deployed in an AppEngine application alongside a React front end.

My web.xml declares two servlets:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>react</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.html</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>react</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        ...
    </servlet-mapping>
...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://www.myapp.com/customtags</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/custom-tags/UserRefTag.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
```

and, of course, the Jersey filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.servlets;com.myapp.tasks;com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.audit;com.myapp.filters</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(js|css|(WEB-INF/jsp)|_ah|ipn|woff|woff2|ui|json|html)/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.audit.AuditLogInterceptor</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.filters.CorsFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/tasks/*</url-pattern>
    ...
</filter-mapping>
```

I've specified, in `appengine-web.xml` the relevant static resources:

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/static/**" expiration="10s"/>
    <!-- react ui resources (eg: manifest.json etc) -->
    <include path="*.html" expiration="10s"/>
    <include path="*.json" expiration="10s"/>
    <include path="*.js" expiration="10s"/>
</static-files>
```

So, ideally, when a user hits an endpoint like `/login` then it should translate to the react servlet, and be directed to `index.html`, which is the react app. ReactRouter should then kick in and render the login page. All static, until it checks for a session or something.

This all works wonderfully well in the devserver. When I load /login, it renders my react app. When the react app calls the backend REST endpoints, they all work.

Then, I put it on appengine (standard environment), and it's a different story. The REST endpoints all respond, but the react app doesn't fire. All I get is: `Error /login` or similar.

When I look in the appengine logs, I see this:

```
:WARN:oaj.EmbeddedServletOptions:RequestDA26342E: The scratchDir you specified: [/base/data/home/apps/g~myapp-alpha/alpha2.419176782209598562/jsp] is unusable
```

Googling around, this error appears to be related to directory permissions in the WebContainer, but that's all obfuscated from me, because this is appengine.

What does this error really mean?
What is the problem?
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, after much hacking, that specifying an HTML file in the  element was what was causing problems.

Whatever webcontainer appengine uses was trying to compile it, but appengine is supposed to pre-compile all JSPs on upload so it doesn't have to do this. Their setup obviously can't cope with that.

The fix was to move and rename `/index.html` into `/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`

It was all perfectly happy then.